# How to post data to Microsoft Forms through APIs

Tags: post, microsoft-forms

I want to set one email field from **SugarCRM** to **Microsoft Forms**. I search through **Graph API** and other platforms and **Microsoft Forms** documentation but did not find anything, I am only getting solutions to get data from **Forms**.

Is it possible to post data / set data in **Microsoft Forms** fields?